# Service Not Responding - Error 1053

Tags: windows-services

The program starts correctly if I double-click it or if I debug it from VS2010, but it doesn't respond when I try running it from `Services.msc`.  It used to work just fine, but I tried to un-register and then re-register the service to fix a different bug and now I get the following error:

```
Could not start the PFAdapterMng service on Local Computer.

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

I tried putting logs at the beginning of `main()`, and I found out that the service stops responding before it even gets there.

I've tried using **Procmon** to figure out if there's some registry key missing, but I couldn't find any problems through Procmon.

I've also tried re-registering the service to try to fix it, since re-registering the service was what caused the error in the first place.  It doesn't seem to fix anything either.

I've stepped through the program with the parameters `-UnregServer` and `-Service` to ensure that the program was being unregistered and registered successfully, and it looks like it's being registered as a service correctly.

Is this because of some error in the registry?  I don't see how or why my program stops responding before it even gets to `main()`.

What else could I try to do to debug this problem?

UPDATE:

So, I tried un-registering the service after trying to run it, and it seemed to work fine.  I look in `services.msc`, and I still see that the application is a service.  In the past, before I got error 1053, it would just disappear after the first time.  I tried un-registering it again, and I got a message box:

Service could not be deleted

So I decided to run the application with the parameter `-UnregServer` inside of Visual Studio 2010 to figure out what the error is.  The function `DeleteService()` is failing with the error:

`ERROR_SERVICE_MARKED_FOR_DELETE`

The service is not removed until all open handles to the service have been closed.  I stepped through the calls to the `CloseServiceHandle()` function and it seems like the handles were closed successfully. The service is also not removed if the service is running.  I checked Process Manager, and the service was not running.  Is the service not being removed because the service stopped responding earlier?

I tried restarting my computer and it was gone.  Still, I don't understand why I have to restart my computer when the service used to un-register without the need of a restart before I was getting error 1053.  Unless of course I can't un-register the service because the service was not stopped because it stopped responding.

I'll keep trying some more things, but I'm running out of ideas.

UPDATE2:

I tried rebuilding the original application, which I know worked as a service.  This means the problem is not related to any of my code.  Something is messed up with the Services Control Manager.  I don't understand why I only get this error with this application.  I have another application which communicates with this application which also needs to be registered as a service.  I have no problems with that application.  It works perfectly.

But for some reason, this application just stopped responding all of a sudden.  I don't know what I changed or broke to cause the service to hang before it even gets to my `main()` function.  The only thing I can think of now to fix the problem is to reformat the server, which is not an option.

Thanks,
Krzys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel stupid.

I've been using Remote Desktop Connection to connect to this server.  Well, the service is starting and erroring out.  The reason I didn't see any errors or message boxes was because they were appearing on the console session.  I was not connected to the console session.  I connected to the server using:

mstsc.exe /admin

And now I can see where the program stops responding.

Feels great to waste 10 hours though.